# How to implement a priority event processing web job with Azure web job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

We have azure webjob which is being triggered from service bus message.So for all messages my webjob function are getting triggered sequentially. There is no priority order to process the message. It treat every message as same priority.

How can I implement a webjob which will process messages as per their priority order.

How to control the number of function instance to run. for example Higher priority messages are allowed to be processed  at a faster speed than the lower priority messages.As long as we have higher priority messages , it will be processed at higher rate than lower priority messages. Once higher priority messages are processed completely, then all the function instances can be used to process all lower priority message

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered Service Bus Topics? There you could have a priority topic, as well as the regular topic. You could have a separate function that runs when a message arrives in the priority topic.

Comment: How to control the number of function instance to run. for example Higher priority messages are allowed to be processed  at a faster speed than the lower priority messages.As long as we have higher priority messages are there , it will be processed at higher rate than lower priority messages. Once higher priority messages are processed completely, then all the function instances can be used to process all lower priority message

Comment: As Service Bus queue offers First In, First Out (FIFO) message delivery to one or more competing consumers. From my experience, if we want to higher priority to be processed first, we need to let higher priority message to be sent first that means we need to order the messages by our customized priority before we send messages to queue.